# Maintain only two commits on git

Tags: git, gitlab

We have a docker... Something or another that reads a Dockerfile/files from a git repository and will automatically launch docker instances based on that.

For my app, I basically have weights that I compute for a network and need to turn that into these Docker instances. (So, basically, I train the network, dump the weights into something like pickle files, and then push them over to git.) Trouble is the weight files are about 4 gigs each, and now after about 15 pushes, the git repository is about 60 gigs.

There's no value for me in keeping around these old weights, at best, I really just want "last known good" and "current".. I've been looking into git rebase -i --root.. But, it's "interactive"

What I really want, is a set of git commands that I can just put into my Makefile that will squash all the commits except the last *two*.. What would be the command line to do that?

Thanks..

Comment: *"There's no value for me in keeping around these old weights, at best, I really just want "last known good" and "current"."* -- then don't put the file into the repository.

Comment: **Don't** put the code and the generated data in the same repository.

Comment: @axiac, yeah, the code is not in the same repository... All that I have in the "repository" is the Dockerfile, the weights, and a python wheel file that knows how to serve the weights, so that it can become a docker instance...

Comment: In this case, instead of a repository you can simply use a different directory (maybe on a different machine) to keep the previous version of the files as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Git is the wrong tool for this.

If you want to use it anyway, here is a way to do that: don't *chain* the commits.  Make each commit independent of all other commits.  Use a branch or tag name (your choice; I illustrate a branch name here for convenience) to identify each commit:

```
$ git checkout --orphan x1
$ git rm -r .; cp /path/to/data/set/x1/* .; git add .
$ git commit -m "data set x1"
```

and:

```
$ git checkout --orphan x2
$ git rm -r .; cp /path/to/data/set/x2/* .; git add .
$ git commit -m "data set x2"
```

and so on.

When a data-set proves worthless, delete the *name* (here `x1`, `x2`, and so on) that refers to it.  The actual data will eventually go away, typically within a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks... I agree that for _this_ purpose, git is the wrong tool.. I suspect the infrastructure team has set things up this way for the web team etc, so that they can drop and recreate their servers just by git push'ing whenever they update the website.. It's just I'm sort of co-opting their system for a kind of different need...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't need version control at all!

But if you want to use Git, you can. However, be aware that

1. You have to create a new branch with no parent. The reason is that Git expects any commit with a parent to have its parent available (recursive). So if you would just delete the chain somewhere, you would get a corrupted repository.
2. Git uses garbage collection to reclaim space. You can force GC locally, but if you push your branches to a repote repository, you need to run GC on the remote machine explicitly, too. You could use hooks for that.

Synopsis:

1. git checkout --orphan temp # Create a new branch "temp" with no commits
2. git cherry-pick master # Pick the last commit from master
3. change files
4. git add -A
5. git commit -m "Comment"
6. git branch -f master temp # Move master branch to temp
7. git checkout master # Change the active branch
8. git branch -d temp # Delete the temp branch
9. git reflog expire --all --expire=0 # Clean reflog references to old commits
10. git gc --prune=all # Force GC to reclaim space

Comment: Thanks! I agree that I don't need version control at all.. This just happens to be the way that I'm supposed to create those docker instances at my own discretion.. (Apparently...) That part isn't up to me, so yeah... I have to do this suboptimal solution..